# Class with only static methods - Enum or not

Tags: java, enums, static

Time after time I have a situation where I have an utility class containing only static methods.

---

**The question is not about the fact of having such classes themselfes, so not a debate about utility classes. We just assume that there is a use case where this class makes sense.**

---

Now I have seen different possibilities to prevent instantiation/extension:

- a private constructor and final class
- using an enum instead of a class

What is the best practice here? Could you elaborate the benefits/drawbacks of the two possibilities?

---

Personally I prefer the enum solution, as it completely prevents instantiation and extension out of the box, but maybe I am wrong.

Thank you already!

Comment: Why is it so important that the class is never instantiated or extended? What happens if that cannot be prevented? IMO such class is no enum semantically, and there's no real benefit to abusing enum's non-instantiability here.

Comment: The instantiation should be prevented as it only contains static methods. So it would make no sense and - possibly - be a waste of resources to somewhere keep a reference to it. At least that is what I intuitively think if I have a class that actually does not need to be an instance at all due to the fact of only containing static methods.

Comment: I agree, it does not need an instance, but I see no tragedy happening if someone manages to instantiate it. By making the default constructor private, you already ensure that no-one will instantiate it accidentally - it takes focused effort to bypass it and create an instance. That only pays off if one can gain an advantage in doing it (e.g. breach security).

Comment: @Jiri Tousek: yeah, but this is closely related to the Singleton Pattern, which fills entire books, thousands of SO questions, blogs and articles, as having an iron hard guaranty that no-one ever creates another instance seems to be the most important thing a programmer can imagine. Unfortunately, even additional `enum`s instances can be created via certain dirty Reflection tricks. So I also recommend to relax, considering a `private` constructor, perhaps containing a `throws` statement, as sufficient and ignore all other imaginable attacks…

Comment: @Holger I thnik we're in agreement here. I see the proposed solution derives from the "enum singleton" approach. I agree a real Singleton is rarely needed. However, while in some rare cases there might be reasons to use it for Singleton, I fail to see any reasons for such concern regarding utility class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer the former.

First of all, using a final class with a private constructor is what I do all the time when I'm writing a utility class. I have never even thought of using enums.

The main reason for not using an enum is that you can still technically write something like this:

```
MyEnum var = MyEnum.valueOf("Hello");
```

and the compiler doesn't say a thing about it, not even IntelliJ IDEA!

Comment: Yeah, and you can get an empty array using `MyEnum.values()`. These are features distracting from the original purpose.